# java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link

Tags: deployment, jboss

I am having spring + google gwt base module where am using JDK 11. Build is completed but once am going to deploy it on JBoss 7.2, it start below this error: I tried most of option available over net and no solution find yet:

> {"WFLYDC0074: Operation failed or was rolled back on all servers. Server failures:" => {"server-group" => {"XXXXX_001" => {"host" => {"my.da.aws.xxx.com" => {"XXXX" => {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit."xxx-ear-2.0.12.ear"."xxx-gwt.war".undertow-deployment" => "java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
> Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory (Module "deployment.xxx-ear-2.0.12.ear.xxx-gwt.war" from Service Module Loader): loader constraint violation: loader 'deployment.xxx-ear-2.0.12.ear.xxx-gwt.war' @a7e44df wants to load interface org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory. A different interface with the same name was previously loaded by 'deployment.xxx-ear-2.0.12.ear' @62541ad5. (org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory is in unnamed module of loader 'deployment.xxx-ear-2.0.12.ear' @62541ad5, parent loader 'app')"}}}}}}}}

I upgrade maven version, I upgrade spring version and I dont have spring boot in my project but still not solution, and even I upgrade guava and gwt version too.

Comment: It looks like you might have Spring included in both your WAR and your EAR.

Comment: Yes James, I have added Spring dependence in both jar but in child war its defined as <scope>provided<scope>. Do you think it can make any problem ?

Comment: If it's marked as provided it should be okay. I would double check you've got no Spring JAR's in your WAR. `oader constraint violation: loader 'deployment.xxx-ear-2.0.12.ear.xxx-gwt.war' @a7e44df wants to load interface org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory. A different interface with the same name was previously loaded by 'deployment.xxx-ear-2.0.12.ear' @62541ad5` is the error that makes me think that *might* be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for replying me, in my case, I found that some spring dependencies are add in parent pom and also was added in child pom even with  tag and once I commented all duplicate dependencies from child then issue was resolved.

Any why...thanks James, will be in touch for further QA if we have !!

Comment: Author has to give his reply on the reply not as new answer.